# updating array value in view in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of values say

```
var myValues = [
[one],[two],[three]
]
```

in my controller of Node (Adonis JS), My Event listener is updating this array after every 1 sec with updated values.

How do I display continuously updated values in view without refreshing page. (When refresh it updates the values) through simple javascript.

I have varibale in view like this,

```
var myViewValues = {{{myValues }}}
```

Comment: can u please elaborate the question ?

Comment: @AnandS my controller is continuously updating the value of an array. I am getting the value of that array in my HTML page and displaying it. Every time I need to refresh the page to get updated value, How do I make this two way binding for server side to client side javascript variables, not to embbed with any HTML element. so I don't need to refresh the page everytime

Comment: You could try using socket.io library to continuosly refresh real time your values on the frontend. Check out their documentation: https://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that returns you the required data. Bind it to another variable and use it in view.

```
//Use .bind() javascript

var obj = {name:"Niladri"};

var greeting = function(a,b,c){
    return "welcome "+this.name+" to "+a+" "+b+" in "+c;
};

//creates a bound function that has same body and parameters 
var bound = greeting.bind(obj); 


console.dir(bound); ///returns a function

console.log("Output using .bind() below ");

console.log(bound("Newtown","KOLKATA","WB")); //call the bound function

/* the output will be 
Output using .bind() below
welcome Niladri to Newtown KOLKATA in WB */
```

Reference: https://www.codementor.io/@niladrisekhardutta/how-to-call-apply-and-bind-in-javascript-8i1jca6jp

Comment: unable to get this

Comment: Answer above is the solution to updating view if controller is getting updated. Please  tell whether the challenge is in updating view or controller. In other words, is the issue in updating the variable myValues or to display the changes happenig to myValues.